# Remove Class if second click in pure Javascript

Tags: javascript, frontend, dom-events

I'm trying to create a simple Lightbox like effect with pure Javascript. I'm trying to figure out how to remove the current class if clicked again. I've tried multiple solutions suggested on Stack Overflow without much success. I don't want to use jQuery or any additional plugins. I think the issue might be with my if/else statement, but can't seem to pinpoint the exact issue.  http://jsfiddle.net/nFNG3/

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', init, false);

function init(){

    function getPop() {
    if (item.className.value == null ){
    item.className += "" + newClass;
    return createFrame();
    }
    else {
    removeClass();
    }


    }
    
    function createFrame() {
    var el = document.createElement('iframe');
    el.setAttribute('id', 'ifrm');
    el.setAttribute('scrolling','no');
    document.body.appendChild(el);
    el.setAttribute('src', 'http://info.kinnser.com/WWW-DEMO-WEBFORM.html');
    }
    
    function removeClass() {
    item.className.value == null;
    
    }



var item = document.getElementById('popit');
var newClass = "light-background";
item.addEventListener('click', getPop, false);
    
}
```

HTML

```
<body>

<div id="container">
    <div id="button-container">
    
        <a href="#" id="popit">Demo Now</a>
        <span id="working"></span>
    </div>
</div>
</body>
```

CSS

```
.light-background{
position:fixed;
width:100%;
height:100%;
background-color:grey;
}

#ifrm{
position:fixed;
width:275px;
height:549px;
z-indez:4;
background-color:white;
top:20%;
left:50%;
margin-top:-50px;
margin-left: -100px;
overflow:hidden;
}
```

Comment: You need to learn the difference between the equality operator == (two equals signs) and the assignment operator = (single equal sign). The line *item.className.value == null* in your removeClass function compares the value to null and **does not set it to null**. You can change the style of an element in JavaScript using the [style property](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_htmldom_css.asp). Removing the style means settings an empty style element.style = ''.

Comment: I tried using the style property item.style.display = 'none'; and it didn't work either.

Comment: You need to set the complete style object to an **empty string** not to 'none', and not the single properties (like display, border, color, visibility, etc.) of the style object but item.style = '';

Comment: Tried that too, didn't work.

Comment: Hey are you trying it directly in fiddle or have you tried it local browser?

Answer (score 0):

Hi do the changes as shown below

```
function getPop() {
  if (!item.className){
       item.className += "" + newClass;
       return createFrame();
  }
   else {
    removeClass();
   }
}

function removeClass() {
    item.className = '';
}
```

Hope this solves your problem